# NullPointerException in DoInvoke because of null receiver

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

Among our users, Samsung phones have this problem, and the cause cannot be found anyway.
Has anyone encountered the same problem? Can you tell me the reason?

```
Process Name: 'packagename'
Thread Name: 'main'
Back traces starts.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{packagename/packagename.ActivityName}: java.lang.NullPointerException: NullPointerException in DoInvoke because of null receiver
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3846)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4022)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: NullPointerException in DoInvoke because of null receiver
    at packagename.ActivityName.onCreate(ActivityName.java)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8207)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8191)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3819)
    ... 11 more
Back traces ends.
```

Partial code：

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    if (!XConstant.DEBUG) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise_bag);

    WindowUtil.setStatusBarFullTransparent(this);

    WindowUtil.setFitSystemWindow(this, false);
}
```

This year, we have discovered more mobile phones experiencing this exception. After testing, we found that this exception occurs when clicking on the notification bar and redirecting to Activity. The following is the code for the notification, which is implemented in Service:

```
val intent = Intent(this, BagExerciseActivity::class.java)
        .putExtras(mBundle!!)
        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED)
/**
 *
 * pendingIntent:封装了Intent的预意图，表示 动作还没有发生，但是会一直保留着这个动作 context 上下文
 * requestCode:请求码 intent ：跳转意图 Flag：标记
 */
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 200,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
var notification: Notification? = null
val intentPlay = Intent(this, TimerService::class.java)
intentPlay.putExtra("setPlay", true)
val intentVoice = Intent(this, TimerService::class.java)
intentVoice.putExtra("setVoice", true)
val intentVibrate = Intent(this, TimerService::class.java)
intentVibrate.putExtra("setVibrate", true)
val intentClose = Intent(this, TimerService::class.java)
intentClose.putExtra("close", true)
val intentFloatWin = Intent(this, TimerService::class.java)
intentFloatWin.putExtra("floatWin", true)
val remoteViews = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.view_notification)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    remoteViews.setInt(R.id.ll_root, "setBackgroundColor",
            ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.white))
}
remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.iv_big, R.drawable.ic_logo_notify)
remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.iv_voice, if (isVoiceOn) R.drawable.ic_voice_on else R.drawable.ic_voice_off)
remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.iv_vibrate, if (isVibrate) R.drawable.ic_zhendong else R.drawable.ic_no_zhen)
remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.iv_play_pause, if (isPlaying) R.drawable.zanting_2 else R.drawable.bofang_2)
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_title, "$proName-$mStepName")
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_sub_title, txt)
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_float_win, if (SPUtils.isFloatwinEnabled(applicationContext)) "关闭悬浮窗" else "打开悬浮窗")
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ll_play_pause, PendingIntent.getService(applicationContext,
        11,
        intentPlay,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ll_voice, PendingIntent.getService(applicationContext,
        12,
        intentVoice,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ll_vibrate, PendingIntent.getService(applicationContext,
        13,
        intentVibrate,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ll_close, PendingIntent.getService(applicationContext,
        14,
        intentClose,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.tv_float_win, View.VISIBLE)
    if (myNotificationListener != null) {//在锻炼页面中，不显示此按钮
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.tv_float_win, View.INVISIBLE)
    } else {
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.tv_float_win, View.VISIBLE)
    }
}
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tv_float_win, PendingIntent.getService(applicationContext,
        15,
        intentFloatWin,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, XConstant.CHANNEL_ID_1_2)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.jpush_notification_icon)
        .setCustomContentView(remoteViews)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .build()
startForeground(XConstant.NOTIFICATION_EXERCISE_ID, notification)
```

Comment: Provide code i will answer

Comment: Something is null in your DoInvoke you need to provide some code for further help.